# How to share files between two Macs at home?

Tags: network, file-sharing

I've turned file sharing on both my Macs here at home. One is an iMac, the other a MacBook Pro. I'm sure there's more to it but I can't seem to figure that out. Both are internet connected through WiFi.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your question is how exactly do you share files. To access the shared files just:

1. While in Finder select **Go > Connect to Server...** or hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.
2. A window will appear, prompting for the Server's URL, which is the File Sharing Computer's network IP, something like `192.168.1.2`. Before the URL you must write `afp://`. So, it will look like `afp://192.168.1.2`.
3. The other Mac's sharing folder will be mounted on your Finder.

**Just so you know**, when you enable the **File Sharing**, beneath the green *light*, the exact URL of **that** computer will be shown. The `afp://your.network.ip.number`thingy.

If you are using Lion, or later, **[Airdrop](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4547)** is, by far, the best option for file sharing. It requires no setup nor special settings, and it sends the files wirelessly, without having both Macs to be connected to the same Wifi network.

Comment: If they are on the same LAN (which they probably are) the "other" Mac should also show up in the sidebar of any Finder window.